# Sinatra, modular style. What did I do wrong?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I use Sinatra modular style, i don't know what going bad. I serach google but didn't find anything

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do
    haml '%h1 Test'
  end

end

run App
```

And a see  test.rb:12:in `<main>': undefined method`run' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
What going wrong?

Comment: `App.run!` rather than `run App`?

Comment: == Sinatra/1.2.1 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.2.8 codename Black Keys)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
/home/maxfry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)
 from /home/maxfry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in

Comment: Can you edit your original post and add all your current code below the current content? It would be much easier for other people to help if we could see what you now have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

did you run it via ruby -rubygems hi.rb (assuming this code is in hi.rb). If so, you don't need run App. Unless you are running it through another framework built on/with Sinatra.

Also might want to include haml...

You have a config.ru:

```
# config.ru
require 'my_app'
run MyApp
```

and a my_app.rb:

```
# my_app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'haml'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

get('/') { haml '%h1 Test' }

  # start the server if ruby file executed directly
  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

then in the folder where the my_app.rb is run this to start the app on localhost:4657:

```
rackup -p 4567
```

Comment: Yes, of cource, i forgot require 'haml' in my example. But this didn't work to.

Comment: Ok, made some edits. I read your original post wrong. This should get you going. if you want to render pages instead of code from the my_app.rb - you can do "haml :pagename" and it will render ./views/pagename.haml

Comment: After this i have a new problem: config.ru:5:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Rack::Builder::App (NameError)

Comment: If i dont use modular style, all render good, i see Test in browser.

Comment: My setup above is in the modular style. You still should have a config.ru.

Comment: Have you installed rack? gem install rack

Comment: Yes yes, i use config.ru and modular style and have a error   config.ru:5:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Rack::Builder::App (NameError)

Comment: hmmm I am not sure... I have never had this much trouble... Consult: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the comment above where the error below is displayed:

```
`start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)
```

This appears when you are trying to bind to an already bound port. Trying a different port number should resolve.

Comment: same with me, this must be the answer